# The embed code for the economic calendar of Trading View

Tags: tradingview-api

The embed code for the economic calendar of Trading View is very difficult to use. Is there a way to display it nicely? I would like to deal with it only with CSS if possible. I am using wordpress. [I want to improve the economic indicator calendar that appears on the home screen of https://nekomama.jp.](https://nekomama.jp) Thank you.

I don't have no idea.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.